# Commands gone when using workflow session in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-workflow

It seems that most common commands are gone when using workflow sessions in powershell:

```
PS P:\> $session = New-PSWorkflowSession -ThrottleLimit 3
PS P:\> Invoke-Command $session {Write-Output "test"}

The term 'Write-Output' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
 + CategoryInfo         : ObjectNotFound: (Write-Output:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
+ PSComputerName        : localhost
```

What can I do to make all the common commands normally available in workflows available through a session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working with a workflow session, you will want to put your commands in a workflow.

```
$session = New-PSWorkflowSession -ThrottleLimit 3

Invoke-Command $session {
        workflow test {
            Write-Output -Input "test"
        }
        test
    }
```

For more info, check out [PowerShell Workflows: Restrictions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions.aspx) and [High Level Architecture of Windows PowerShell Workflow (Part 1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/15/high-level-architecture-of-windows-powershell-workflow-part-1.aspx)